# cx_Freeze app will not open in command prompt and prints no errors

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

To start I am using python 3.6.5 and cx_Freeze 6.0b1 on Windows 10.

I have a program I built using wxPython and want to freeze the code using cx_Freeze.  I have been working on this for days and read what I feel like every post in regards to this issue already, and still have not had any success.  Running the .exe in the command prompt or double clicking the application will not open.  I have also tried to change the `base` between `None`, `Console` and `Win32GUI` all with no success.

At this point I am about to give up.  I would be happy just to get an error message to chase down.

`setup.py`:

```
import os
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Chad\Anaconda3\Library\lib\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Chad\Anaconda3\Library\lib\tk8.6'

include_lst = []
package_lst = ['numpy', 'scipy', 'pulp', 'pubsub', 'sqlite3',
               'numpy.core._methods']
exclude_lst = ['matplotlib', 'tkinter', 'PyQt4.QtSql', 'PyQt5',
               'PyQt4.QtNetwork', 'PyQt4.QtScript', 'sqlalchemy']

base = None

setup (
       name='',
       version='',
       author='',
       author_email='',
       options={'build_exe':
                   {'packages': package_lst,
                    'excludes': exclude_lst,
                   'include_files': include_lst,
                   'include_msvcr': True
                   }
                },
       executables=[Executable('main.py',  base=base, icon=None)]
       )
```

I can get the following program to freeze without any issues, so maybe it is not a cx_Freeze issue but an issue in my main.py file?

```
 if __name__.endswith('__main__'):
        print('Hello World')
```

As far as preparing a minimal example I apologize but I am not exactly sure how to go about it as this program does use an sqlite3 db and about 21 in house modules. However, in trying I think the problem comes from connecting to the db, so below is a basic example, but without the db I doubt you will will be get to reproduce due to the db issue.  With this code once I freeze it nothing happpens on the command it just goes to the next line.

`main.py`:

```
import util
import wx


class MasterPage (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.conn = util.DataBaseManager.DataBaseManager()

        self.createFrame()

    def createFrame(self):
        self.width, self.height = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        self.SetTitle('Test')
        self.SetSize(wx.Size((self.width-50, self.height-50)))
        self.SetMinSize((1080, 720))
        self.W, self.H = self.GetSize()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onQuit)
        self.Centre()
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar(2)
        self.statusbar.SetStatusWidths([self.W * 67, self.W * .23])

    def onQuit(self, event):
        """Checks to make sure the user wants to leave the program"""
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,'Do you really want to quit?',
                               'Confirm Exit',
                                wx.ICON_QUESTION|wx.OK|wx.CANCEL )
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
                self.Destroy()

if __name__.endswith('__main__'):
    app = wx.App()
    MasterPage(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

`util.DataBaseManager.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
import sqlite3


class DataBaseManager(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """Creates a connection to the database requested"""
        try:
            self.db = self.findDataPath('master.db')
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db)
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(e)

    def executePandasQuery(self, sql_statement):
        self.df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_statement, self.conn)
        self.conn.commit()
        return self.df

    def executeCursorQuery(self, sql_statement, values):
        if values == 'na':
            self.cursor.execute(sql_statement)
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(sql_statement, values)
        self.conn.commit()
        return self.cursor

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()

    def findDataPath(self, filename):
        """
        Get the correct path for outside data works with cx_freeze
        :params str filename: the filename looking for
        :returns: the absolute path of the file.
        :rtype: string
        """
        if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
            # The application is frozen
            p = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
            p = '{}\{}'.format(p,filename)
        else:
            # The application is not frozen
            p = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
            p = '{}\{}'.format(p,filename)
        return p
```

Edit #2

I think this is an issue with importing my self-defined module `util`.  If I put a print statement right before the `import util` in `main.py`, the print statement will run but then the app closes, and command prompt goes to next line.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the code you want to freeze. Try for example the `wxPython` [sample script](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/tree/master/cx_Freeze/samples/wx) from the `cx_Freeze` repository and report any error message you get if it does not work.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my question.  I truly appreciate your time and have added some code.

Comment: No worries regarding the minimal example. The additional information you have provided is useful already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the problem to connect the database: how do you create the database file `master.db` in your frozen application and where is it located? Looking at the code you have posted, I understand the following:

- In the non-frozen application, the `master.db` file is in the parent directory of the `util` package directory (which is the main application directory)
- You do not tell `cx_Freeze` to explicitly include the `master.db` file into the build directory. As this file is in the main application directory, it does not get automatically included by `cx_Freeze` (have a look into the build directory to see whether you see the file).

I see at least two alternatives to solve this:

1. Move the `master.db` file into the `util` package directory in the non-frozen application. `cx_Freeze` should include the whole `util` directory this including the database file. Change your `findDataPath` function to:

   ```
   def findDataPath(self, filename):
       """
       Get the correct path for outside data works with cx_freeze
       :params str filename: the filename looking for
       :returns: the absolute path of the file.
       :rtype: string
       """

       p = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
       p = os.path.join(p, filename)
       return p
   ```

   This should work both for the non-frozen and for the frozen application. (Remark: use `os.path.join` to join paths in a platform-independent way).
2. Keep the `master.db` file in main directory of the non-frozen application and tell `cx_Freeze` to include the database file into the `lib` subdirectory of the `build` directory, which is the parent directory of the `util` package directory in the frozen application. You can let `cx_Freeze` include a file into a specific location by passing a tuple (`source`, `destination`) to the corresponding entry of the `include_files` list option in the setup script:

   ```
   include_lst = [('master.db', os.path.join('lib', 'master.db'))]
   ```

   Change your `findDataPath` function to:

   ```
   def findDataPath(self, filename):
       """
       Get the correct path for outside data works with cx_freeze
       :params str filename: the filename looking for
       :returns: the absolute path of the file.
       :rtype: string
       """

       p = os.path.dirname((os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
       p = os.path.join(p, filename)
       return p
   ```

   This should also work both for the non-frozen and for the frozen application.

Comment: Once again you saved me big time jpeg.  Thank you so much for all your help.  I really really appreciate your time on all of this!